# cmake doesn't create the dartconfiguration.tcl

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a bash script that launch cmake and ctest and works.

I have developed another script in python with the same functions but I get this problem :

```
WARNING: No nightly start time found please set in CTestConfig.cmake or DartConfig.cmake Problem initializing the dashboard.
```

I have verified that ctestconfigcmake is at the root and copied to my project and include ctest is present in cmakelists.txt.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you please add a [mvce] of your `CMakeLists.txt` file also. If I would have to guess you are probably missing the [`include(Dart)`](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Generating_Testing_Files) line.

Comment: Yes I don't found include(Dart) in CMakeLists.txt , I must add it in cmakeconfig ? I add that I use CDASH.

Comment: @AnatoEm I'm also having `include(Dart)` in my project and I'm not using [tag:cdash]. You could consider this requirement an issue in CMake, but let's just say you need it to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the error. The cmake command wasn't good and don't contain include ctest. I was used subprocesss.run so the arguments must be as list and different from arguments in bash.